# How to use FirebaseUserMetadata to check new user?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I want to check if the user is new or not by using Firebase. I have a button to SignIn with google

```
  Future<FirebaseUser> googleSignIn() async {

try {
  loading.add(true);
  GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
  await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );


  FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;


  loading.add(false);
  return user;
} catch (error) {
  return error;
}
```

}

If I add FirebaseUserMetadata I have this : A value of type 'Future' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUserMetadata'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'FirebaseUserMetadata'.

I think what I have to do is to compare lastSignInTimestamp and creationTimestamp from FirebaseUserMetadata.

```
FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
if(new user){
updateDataNewUser(...)
}
else{
updateDataUser(...)
}
```

How I can get this data from FirebaseUserMetadata in my case ?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it's working, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the user is new or not, try the following:

```
AuthResult user = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
print(user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser);
```

[`isNewUser`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/additional_user_info.dart) returns whether the user is new or existing

Answer (score 0):

```
 private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct: GoogleSignInAccount) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.id!!)
    showProgressDialog()

    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.idToken, null)
    mAuth!!.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {

                firebaseUser = mAuth!!.currentUser

                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
                    .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if (!task.isSuccessful) {

                            return@OnCompleteListener
                        }

                        // Get new Instance ID token

                       // this is a new user
                        buildThatNoob()

                    })

            } else {

                OurToast.myToast(this, "Something went Wrong ... try again later")
                val i = Intent(baseContext, Launcher::class.java)
                startActivity(i)
                finish()
            }

            hideProgressDialog()
        }
}
```